# J2EE Pet Store example in other languages/frameworks?

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm doing some comparison of web frameworks, and would like to compare "Apples to Apples".  As far as I know, the most famous web app for such uses is the J2EE Pet Store example:

http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/app-arch/app-arch4.html

I've found at least one implementation in Ruby on Rails:

http://www.anassina.com/projects/railspetstore/

However, all the other links I found appear dead.  Does anyone know of other implementations?  Or better yet, someplace that collects all of them?

Answer (score 1):

Spring 2.5.6 samples has a JPetStore, written using Spring.  I don't know how it compares to the J2EE Pet Store.  I don't see it shipping with Spring 3.

You should be aware that the Pet Store is rather long in the tooth.  I believe it's based on EJB 1.0; J2EE is 1999 terminology.  I'm not sure that it's the "hello world" of framework development.

There was also a controversial benchmark when Microsoft first came out with .NET.  They wrote a .NET version of Pet Store and published the results on The Server Side.  A firestorm of criticism ensued.

I'm not aware of a zoo for Pet Store implementations.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'm dating myself. :-) Do you know of any other canonical example people are using instead for such shootouts? Is a blog the new "Hello, World!" for web frameworks?

Comment: No, I think it should be something like an address book, like "Barebones Spring".  Small but meaty.